# svn commit -> push to git

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

We have a central SVN server, which is used a lot.
We also have a gitlab server, which might be used in the future.

For now I'm looking for a way for the SVN server to push every commit to the Gitlab server as well, thereby allowing me to use the Gitlab CI.

A nice to have would be that if I create a tag, it is pushed to the master branch, build, tested and published as my .yaml file already describes.

I've been searching for an easy solution, but have not been able to find it yet.
Is there an easy way to perform this action?

Comment: SubGit in sync mode?!

Comment: Yes, that should be a possibility, though the license is quite heavy, I'm rather looking for a diy solution